# navigation bar custom height

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I want to remove the distance from the status bar to the navigation bar. how to do it?

[image]

```
if ([self.navBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
{
    [self.navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-top"]
                      forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

Comment: if it helpful for u , you can vote up and acept to let other people know if they can use it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
```

or u can create your custom one.

[Designing a Custom iPhone App Navigation Bar](http://designm.ag/tutorials/designing-a-custom-iphone-app-navigation-bar/)

or

[costume style](http://devinsheaven.com/create-a-custom-uinavigationbar-style/)